# Multiplication of a vector by a TRS matrix doesn't seem to work

Tags: c#, matrix, unity-game-engine, vector

Unity 3D 5.4 allows to create a Matrix4x4, set its TRS values via [Matrix4x4.SetTRS](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Matrix4x4.SetTRS.html) and multiply a point by that matrix to apply the transformation. I would expect the following code to print out the *translated* point but the translation doesn't seem to take place.

```
m = Matrix4x4.identity;
m.SetTRS(new Vector3(-10f, 4f, 0f), Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f)), Vector3.one);

Vector3 P = new Vector3(10f, 1f, 0f);

Debug.Log("P': " + m * P);
```

The code prints out

```
P': (10.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
```

instead of

```
P': (0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0)
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To transform a `Vector3` point using a `Matrix4x4`, you need to use either [`Matrix4x4.MultiplyPoint()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Matrix4x4.MultiplyPoint.html) or [`Matrix4x4.MultiplyPoint3x4()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Matrix4x4.MultiplyPoint3x4.html). So in your case, I would try:

```
Debug.Log("P': " + m.MultiplyPoint3x4(P));
```

Also, as a tip - a `Quaternion` indicating no rotation can be represented by `Quaternion.identity`, so you don't need to keep calling `Quaternion.Euler()` for that (if that was your intention).

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I completely missed the MultiplyPoint functions. Thank you! But why doesn't m * P just work? Mathematically, it makes sense.

Comment: Yep, I had to go digging through the docs myself the first time I wanted to use them. Remember that a `Matrix4x4` is, well, 4x4 - and a `Vector3` is only 3x1 in dimensions. Multiplying them outright won't properly transform the point. (Though, perhaps a `Vector4` version of the point with the last value being a 1 might work...? Otherwise, Unity's doing a bit more behind the scenes here.)